# Difference between OAuth2RestOperations and OAuth2RestTemplate in Spring oAuth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

What exactly is the difference between OAuth2RestOperations and OAuth2RestTemplate. And when should we use OAuth2RestOperations and when should we use OAuth2RestTemplate ?

(Looking for a functional explanation.)

Comment: Read : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.html  https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestOperations.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OAuth2RestOperations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestOperations.html) is an **interface** that is actually implemented by [OAuth2RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.html) **class**.

From OAuth2RestTemplate documentation you can read:

> Rest template that is able to make OAuth2-authenticated REST requests with the credentials of the provided resource.

Therefore, if you want to use the out of the box class then you can use OAuth2RestTemplate, however you can create your own custom implementation to suit your needs by implementing `OAuth2RestOperations` in case OAuth2RestTemplate is not for your needs.

Comment: So, 'out of the box' means we can have our own implementation on actions like access token request, how many retires with failed access token etc ?

Comment: Out of the box means that spring gives you an already implemented class that you can use for standard usage. However, standard is not always the case, you might want to do a custom logic. In my case, I never had to create such thing. You can even use the common RestTemplate and attach headers manually using entities if you dont want OAuth2RestTemplate.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the info. :)